# IndexOutOfRangeException: Array Index is out of Range Unity

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, indexing, unity-game-engine

I was trying to build a Pathfinding A* code, but keep getting an Array Index error. I have tried tweaking with the x and y, but no luck so far.
Here is the code.

```
public int columns = 9;                                                      //Columns and rows to set up the board
public int rows = 9;                                                //This number are the usable tiles, the complete board is 11 by 11
                                                                    //With a border of 1 tile

public Node[,] graph;

//Class Node
public class Node
{
    public List<Node> neighbours;                                                   //List of all the neighbours nodes (4Directions)

    public Node()
    {
        neighbours = new List<Node>();
    }
}

//Sets up the outer walls and floor (background) of the game board.
void BoardSetup()
{
    for (int x = -1; x < columns + 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = -1; y < rows + 1; y++)
        {
            Edited out Code, don't think has anything to do with my problem.
        }
    }
}

//Creates the graph to use Pathfinding
void GeneratePathfindingGraph()
{
    //Create graph
    graph = new Node[columns, rows];

    for (int x = -1; x < columns + 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = -1; y < rows + 1; y++)
        {

            graph[x, y] = new Node();

            Add the 4 cardinal adjacent tiles
            if (x != - 1)
                graph[x, y].neighbours.Add(graph[x - 1, y]);      
            if (x != columns - 1)
                graph[x, y].neighbours.Add(graph[x + 1, y]);       //Where I am getting the error
            if (y != - 1)
                graph[x, y].neighbours.Add(graph[x, y - 1]);
            if (y != rows - 1)
                graph[x, y].neighbours.Add(graph[x, y + 1]);
        }
    }
}

//SetupScene initializes our level and calls the previous functions to lay out the game board
public void SetupScene(int level)
{
    //Creates the outer walls and floor.
    BoardSetup();

    //Creates the Node map to use Pathfinding
    GeneratePathfindingGraph();
}
```

}

I have edited out most of the code in this class, I don't think it has much to do with the problem.

Comment: Any specific reason for `int x = -1` in your loop?

Comment: Why do you start your loops at `-1`? . Note that your `if`s always check only _one_ variable (`x` or `y`), so you definitly run into a `graph[-1, -1]` in the very first iteration. `-1` is not a valid index for an array. Start your loops at `0` and it should work fine (assuming the rest of your algorithm is correct, which I did not check).

Comment: `if (x != columns - 1) //graph[x, y].neighbours.Add(graph[x + 1, y]);` `x` = -1, `columns - 1` = 8. There for you try to access `graph[-1,-1]` which isn't possible as every index starts at 0.

Comment: Thanks everybody!
I didn't know every index must start at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change all the initialization in the loop like `x = -1;`to `x = 0;`
Arrays always start's with a ZERO.